# Interpolate random zero pixels in an image

Tags: python, image-processing

I have an image that has some pixels are zero in random locations. Some of these pixels can be neighbors so that a small area of zero value can be formed, so by looping over all these zero value pixels and finding neighboring pixels for interpolation seems not working here. Of course I can do iterative interpolation till all such zero pixels are filled. But is there a quick and clean way to do this?

Comment: Would it upset the rest of the image too much if you just added `1` to every pixel?

Comment: that is fine, but how can that help for the interpolation?

Comment: If you add `1` to every pixel you will no longer have any areas of zero pixels and you won't need to interploate to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the size of the voids is limited and if you accept averaging as the interpolation technique, you can resort to [integral images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table) for fast computation.

The trick is to consider two images, one with the gray values and one with 0/1 values (0 in voids). Using integral images, you can efficiently compute the sums in a sliding window of the size you like. The sum of the binary image will give you the count of nonzero pixels inside the window. When dividing the gray sum by the binary sum, you get the average of the nonzero values, which can be used to fill the voids.

If the window is fully covered with 0's (too large void), you end up with 0/0 indetermination.

If the window is large, the averaged values will be very smooth and will not correspond to the neighboring nonzero values.

Answer (score 2):

Quick way: when you meet a zero pixel, scan left, right, up and down until you find four nonzero neighbors; adjust the interpolation weights as a function of the distance. (Also possible with 8-ways scans.)

Less quick way: you can grow a complete neighborhood of the zero pixel one layer at a time, until you find all surrounding nonzero pixels and compute a weighted average of these.

[For efficiency you can also fill the void with seed fill and trace the outer contour of the void and process all pixels in the void in a single go. This is more involved.]

For large holes, [inpainting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inpainting) techniques will do marvels, but they can be highly sophisticated.

Comment: i do not need complex inpainting. i just need a quick way to fill up some random 0 valued pixels with reasonable values from the closest neighbors... your first approach is what i though of. It definitely works but i though there must be a better way to do that.

Comment: In what way "better" ?

Comment: can be parallelly done rather than searching for each 0 pixels

Comment: Look at my comment between brackets []. By filling the voids you will process A (for Area) pixels collectively. If you use all P (for Perimeter) pixels on the outer outline, the workload for interpolation will be in any case O(A.P). This dominates the time for filling (O(A)) and outline tracing (O(P)).